# Cómo redirigir a un usuario según su rol en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero redirigir a un usuario según su rol en Laravel

Este es mi vista que posee @can

```
 @can('home')   
<li class="lista"><a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="enlace"><span 
class="der"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></span>Inicio</a></li>
@endcan
 @can('misiones')   
<li class="lista"><a href="{{ route('products.anuncios') }}" 
class="enlace"><span class="der"><span class="fa fa-pencil" ></span> 
</span>Mis anuncios</a></li>
@endcan
```

> este es el controlador

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

se que realizando un if me ayudara a realizando pero viendo que tiene implenedato el @can la vista pues me confundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La direciva `@can` te sirve para mostrar/ocultar contenido dependiendo del rol y/o permiso del usuario. Por ejemplo, si el único rol que puede añadir usuarios es el de *"admin"* un menú podría tener la siguiente estructura:

#### admin

- Inicio
- Publicaciones
- Usuarios <---- esto se restringiría con la directiva `@can`

#### escritor

- Inicio
- Publicaciones

En cambio, lo que entiendo que deseas realizar es una redirección del usuario a una vista específica dependiendo del rol que este posee. Este tipo de medidas no se realizan en el frontend sino desde el backend. Por lo que tendrías que depositar esta lógica en el controlador, como puedes ver en esta [otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36815776/7117697) respuesta:

#### LoginController.php

```php
use AuthenticatesUsers;

// ...

public function authenticated($request , $user){
    if($user->role=='admin'){
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard') ;
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('regular.dashboard') ;
    }
}
```

PD: Notar que este método es invocado por el Trait `AuthenticatesUsers`, que es el que tienes implementado en tu controlador, y que el método `authenticated` devuelve el nombre de la ruta en un string. Por lo que puedes definir esas rutas como sigue:

#### routes/web.php

```php
Route::get('/dashboard-admin', function (){
    return view('views.vista_para_admin');
})->name('admin.dashboard'); // <--- este es el nombre que busca el controlador.

Route::get('/dashboard', function (){
    return view('views.vista_para_user');
})->name('regular.dashboard'); // <--- este es el nombre que busca el controlador.
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando la respuesta anterior. Me di la tarea de editarlo un poco para redireccionar segun los roles mediante una relación.

```
$userb = User::with('roles')->where('id', $user->id)->first();

$role= $userb->roles->first()->name;

if($role=='admin'){
    return redirect()->route('admin') ;
}
```

Nota: name podría ser el id.

Answer (score 0):

Trataba de implementar las soluciones dadas anteriormente pero al parecer cambiaron cosas para laravel 9 y no me funcionaron así que busqué una tercer solución

Primero llamas los archivos Auth y HasRoles, de la siguiente manera:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
```

(Estos archivos ya tienen los métodos para el usuario que inició sesión y para saber que role tiene)

Después haces uso de HasRole en la clase LoginController:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers, HasRoles;
```

Y finalmente sólo sobreescribes el metodo redirecTo el cual es el predeterminado de laravel para redirigir y aplicas la lógica para redireccionar en el archivo LoginController:

```
public function redirectTo(){
//en el metodo hasAnyRole ingresa el nombre del o los roles que se redirigen a la vista deseada

        if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('Administrador','Administrador2')){
            return $this->redirectTo = route('viewAdm') ;
            
        }elseif(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('UsuarioNormal')){
            return $this->redirectTo = route('home') ;
        }
    }
```

Mi codigo final de LoginController quedó así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers, HasRoles;
    
    public function redirectTo(){

        if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('Adm1','Adm2')){
            return $this->redirectTo = route('viewAdm') ;
            
        }elseif(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('Usuario')){
            return $this->redirectTo = route('home') ;
        }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Obviamente no se olviden de implementar las rutas correspondientes en su archivo web.php!
Espero haber ayudado! :)